# Navigate back to shell window with different regions

Tags: c#, wpf, viewmodel, prism

I have shell window with 4 regions and by clicking Settings button of 1st User Control one of view navigates to another view[image: Shell with multiple regions]

[image: Navigated region]

I have navigated to new view by clicking on Settings button on header.

MainHeader.xaml

```
 <Button Grid.Column="2" x:Name="SettingsBtn" Content="Settings" Command="{Binding appSettingCommand}"/>
```

MainHeaderViewmodel.cs

public class MainHeaderViewModel : BindableBase, IDisposable
{

```
    private readonly IRegionManager _regionManager;

    private readonly IDialogService dialogService;
    public DelegateCommand appSettingCommand { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand viewSettingCommand { get; set; }
    public MainHeaderViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager, IDialogService dialogservice)
    {
        _regionManager = regionManager;
        this.dialogService = dialogservice;
        appSettingCommand = new DelegateCommand(ApplicationSettingHandler);
        viewSettingCommand = new DelegateCommand(ViewSettingHandler);
        
    }

    
    private void ApplicationSettingHandler()
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.SettingsDisplayRegion,"ApplicationSettings");
    }

    private void ViewSettingHandler()
    {
        _regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.SettingsDisplayRegion, "SavedSettings");
    }

    
}
```

By clicking on back button of navigated view, I want to return to shell window with all regions as shown in 1st image . I want to know what is the best way to achieve this and where to make changes in the code

Comment: What do you mean by "shell window"?

Comment: @Dai It acts like MainWindow which consists of regions having views

Comment: The term "shell" is widely understood to refer to the user's interface to the OS, be it a command-line (e.g. `bash`, `cmd`, etc), or a GUI file-explorer and process navigator (i.e. `explorer.exe`, macOS Finder, etc) - in your case you should refer to it as an "MDI Window" or "tool window host" or similar - but not "shell".

Comment: The root window of a prism app is called the shell. Usually mainwindow. I think there should (just) be some mention of prism in the question as well as in the list of tags. This is pretty much a prism specific question and mention of MDI or tool window host is unlikely to be useful.  I'm not so clear on "previous shell". I would expect one mainwindow to be THE shell.

Comment: @Andy Ah, my apologies - I didn't know Prism had its own terminology like that.

Comment: The 1st image consist of mainwindow(shell window) having 4 regions and from header region there's a button(Settings) which navigates to another view. On Clicking Back button of navigated view I want it to return to shell window as it was there before

Comment: I don't know how common usage is exactly but I'm not so sure it's prism specific. I've  heard the term shell used for any thin container you expose everything from. Or put everything inside. I would often have a totally empty window binds content to datacontext and datatemplate out everything inside it.

Comment: @Haukinger Hi! Do you know anything anything about to navigate back to shell window with all its previous regions?